1980ish video about a spaceman rescuing musicians from Atlantis?
Bear with me, this one's really obscure.
Back in, probably, about 1980 in the UK, I saw an short animated film on TV, possibly a music video. It was about the fall of Atlantis; we see the city sinking beneath the sea, and an Atlantean orchestra calmly playing music as the waves roll in... and then spaceship arrives, and a man in a spacesuit picks up the musicians in bubbles and takes them away to safety. We then see them continuing to play, in space.
This had a big impression on me at the time. Does anyone know what it might have been?
Other useful things I remember:
(a) I remember watching it, then changing to another channel (there were only three in those days) and seeing the same video playing again. So I suspect this may have been some kind of animation award winner, and both the BBC and ITV were covering it. But if it was high profile enough to warrant coverage on both channels, I would think it would be easier to find.
(b) the animation style was, um, very Euro: hyper-deformed figures. I remember the musicians looking a bit like preying mantises. I'm not sure if this helps. I definitely remember the title card showing up in some weird language I'd never heard of at the time, like French.
(c) there was no dialogue, just video and music, so it may have been a music video; at the time I wasn't aware there was any difference between ordinary cartoons and music videos.
This has been bugging me for more time than I like to think about. Any ideas?

If this was a music video then it's off-topic for this site.

Good thing it's not a music topic then, isn't it!

You seem to think it might be one in your question.

If you can identify this as any specific music video, I will gladly delete my question...
